# GroupBy and Sum with two Different period time - Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get sum of my products amount in different period of times in just one row.

for example:

```
ID     Date       Amount
-------------------------
1     2017/01/01   10
1     2017/01/01   12
1     2017/04/03   5
2     2017/01/02   10
```

I need to get sum for spring season and summer season of each product, so we have this for product 1:

```
ID     SumSpring    SumSummer
-----------------------------
1        22            5
```

I have used this code:

```
    var pDetails = ordersTotal.Select(g => new
                                {
                                    g.ProductID,
                                    DateType = (((String.Compare(g.BuyDate, "2017/01/01") >= 0 && String.Compare(g.BuyDate, "2017/03/30") <= 0)) ? "Spring" : "Summer"),
                                    g.Amount
                                }).GroupBy(x => new { id = x.ProductID, type = x.DateType }).Select(x => new
                                {
                                    ProductID = x.Key.id,
                                    SumSpring = (x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Spring").Count() == 0 ? 0 : x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Spring").Sum(z => z.Amount)),
                                    SumSummer = (x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Summer").Count() == 0 ? 0 : x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Summer").Sum(z => z.Amount)),
                                });
```

but it returns several rows for each product which is not what I expected and I do not know why!

This is the output for one product:

```
ID     SumSpring    SumSummer
-----------------------------
1        22            0
1        0             5
```

two rows for one product, but it should be one!

Comment: have you tried removing `amount = x.Amount` from the groupby expression?

Comment: thanks I have edited my post.

Comment: Could it be that you actually want a sale volumne for spring and summer for every product? So even if a product was not sold in that quarter it should be listed as 0? And even if no product at all was sold in a quarter you want to list every product with 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the quarter of a year in this way:

```
int quarter = (month + 2) / 3;
```

But don't include it in the `GroupBy`, you only want to group by `ProductID`

```
var pDetails = ordersTotal.Select(x => new
{
    x.ProductID,
    x.Amount,
    Quarter = (x.BuyDate.Month + 2) / 3
})
.Where(x => x.Quarter == 1 || x.Quarter == 2)  // it seems you only want these
.GroupBy(x => x.ProductID)
.Select(g => new
{
    ProductID = g.Key,
    SumSpring = g.Where(x => x.Quarter == 1)
                 .Select(x => x.Amount)
                 .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                 .Sum(),
    SumSummer = g.Where(x => x.Quarter == 2)
                 .Select(x => x.Amount)
                 .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                 .Sum()
});
```

Note that this query doesn't care about the year. But it seems you don't care about it anyway.

Comment: removing the Count() (for making sum 0) is wrong and it should be there, because maybe a product does not have an entry for spring or summer so the sum will be 0.

Comment: @Nofuzy use `DefaultIfEmpty` before `Sum`: `g.Where(x => x.Quarter == 1).Select(x => x.Amount).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum()`. Will be more readable then `if.. else`

Comment: @Nofuzy: i have edited my query to take it into account (like Fabio)

Comment: @TimSchmelter  @Fabio it gives this error: `Unsupported overload used for query operator DefaultIfEmpty.`

Comment: @Nofuzy, if your LINQ provider does not support `DefaultIfEmpty` - then you can use your original code but instead of `.Count()` use `Any()`

Comment: how to use `Any()`?

Comment: `x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Spring").Any() == false ? 0 : x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Spring").Sum(z => z.Amount)`

Comment: thanks @Fabio, I used this: `!x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Spring").Any() ? 0 : x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Spring").Sum(z => z.Amount)`

Answer (score 2):

Try following.  the major issue is that you  are grouping by Amount :

```
           var pDetails = ordersTotal.Select(g => new
            {
                ProductID = g.ProductID,
                DateType = ((g.BuyDate >= DateTime.Parse("1/1/17")) && (g.BuyDate <=  DateTime.Parse("3/30.17"))) ? "Spring" : "Summer",
                Amount = g.Amount
            }).GroupBy(x => new { id = x.ProductID}).Select(x => new
            {
                ProductID = x.Key.id,
                SumSpring = x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Spring").Sum(z => z.Amount),
                SumSummer = x.Where(z => z.DateType == "Summer").Sum(z => z.Amount),
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, removing the Count() for making sum 0 is wrong and it should be there, because maybe a product does not have an entry for spring or summer so the sum will be 0.

Comment: What is wrong with having null for the Sum?  It will indicate a difference between when there is no entry and entry where values add up to zero.  You could have positive and negative values.